# Pass multiple values to the report builder parameter

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting-services, report, reporting

How to programmatically send several values to a report parameter? I pass this way:

```
ReportParameter id_shift = new ReportParameter("id_sectionshift", string.Join(", ", GlobalVariable.arrIdShift));
reportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { id_shift });
this.reportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

After that, I see this in my report:
[image]

If I fix it manually like this, then everything works:
  [image]
Tried to change "," on ";" Does not help. Tried to make a footnote "\ n", also does not help. I pounded on the wheel, clapped the hood - I did not drag the method of the pump, I ask for help. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Try this: `reportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(id_shift);` instead of `reportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { id_shift });`

Comment: @R.Richards Thank you very match.